# .config folder killed my login; How to recover?

Tags: login, configuration

**Problem**: My machine crashed (Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.36.4). I tried to reboot but didn‘t get past my login screen (greeted by black screen). Following [this guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/) I moved my .config to .config.old. After that I was able to graphically log in again. But obviously most of my configurations we‘re lost.

**Question**: How can I find the file(s) in .config that caused the problem? In other words: How can I recover the „working parts“ of my .config folder?

**Additional information**: The crash began with Discord crashing. At the same time the fans started to go wild. Since I had several problems with my kern.log and syslog files in /var/log becoming to large I suspected them to be the problem. They were about 5GB each and rapidly growing. I tried opening them to see what’s causing the problem but they were already too large to open. I then removed them. I then proceeded to the reboot mentioned above.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Link: https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/

Comment: :"but they were already too large to open"  tail -f logfile or use less or more. Never use  an editor. " I then removed them." Never remove log files. Use "> {file}" to empty them. removing also removes permissions plus some software might have the file open and crash due to it being gone when it expected it to be there.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the advice!

Comment: but did you find out what the error is that is in the log files? those will come back again and soon too.

Comment: @Rinzwind No. Unfortunately I didn‘t. Last time I ran into the problem of log files getting too large it was a package called „baloo“-something. I don‘t remember the full name. I could savely remove it which solved the problem.

Comment: baloo? that is the kde file indexer. If that was the one `balooctl disable` would have been the safer option ;-) Make it an answer and accept it! You'll get some reputation and upvotes.

Comment: @Rinzwind Oops... Yes it was that one. I had it installed because I had tried KDE once. Sorry for being such a noob :|
I now opened my syslog (which is again growing at quite a rate) using your method. It says that snap.nextcloud.mdns-publisher.service is failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113365/discussion-between-pewepow-and-rinzwind).